# Queue implementation in python gives error on size

Tags: python, queue

I'm new to Python, thus the question. This is my implementation of a Queue

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = None
        self.marker = None
        self.size = 0

    def push(self, item):
        self.size += 1
        curr = Node(item)
        if self.top is None:
            self.top = curr
            self.marker = curr
        else:
            self.marker.next = curr
            self.marker = curr

    def pop(self):
        if self.top is None:
            raise Exception("Popping an empty queue")
        curr = self.top
        self.size -= 1
        if self.top is self.marker:
            self.top = None
            self.marker = None
        else:
            self.top = self.top.next
        return curr

    def peek(self):
        return self.top.value

    def size(self):
        return self.size

    def isempty(self):
        return self.size == 0
```

The Node class is defined as follows,

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value=None, next=None):
        self.value = value;
        self.next = next
```

This implementation works fine for most of the methods except when I call size.
This call,

```
 print(queue.size())
```

Results in the following exception,

```
print(queue.size())
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Can't seem to understand what the issue is here.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you use the same name, `size`, for both an integer attribute and for a method. Try changing the integer attribute name (and all references to it) to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave an attribute and a method the same name, **size**.  This confuses name resolution (to you; the interpreter has its rules tightly in place).  Check your name resolution precedence; I think you'll find that the attribute takes precedence in this case.  Thus, **queue.size** resolves to an integer, not a function.